# Jquery: set read-only text-box width dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a read only text-box, its value is coming from database.. 
I wants its width to be set based on text length.. I am not sure which jQuery event I need to call once text box gets value from DB..

Now I have `onkeypress()` event..Which works fine with normal text box.. Instead of `Onkeypress()` I want to make use of any other event which fires once value stored in that read only text box.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span><p>Hello, my name is </p></span>

<span> <input id="txt" value="I am coming from db" readonly="readonly" class="form" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 8) + 'px';" type="text" >
</span>
```

Comment: The input is `readonly` and you can't type any think in it. So why you want to fire `onkeypress` event?

Comment: Naresh Shetty If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's how http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234… then return here and do the same with the tick/check mark till it turns green. This informs the community, a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size attribute in an input let you control the width to fit dynamically, using that and `keypree` `change` events you can make it to fit when the input value changes.

```js
$('#txt').bind("keypress change ",function(){
 $(this).attr('size',$(this).val().length);
});
$('#change').click(function(){
  $('#txt').val('1234566').change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span><p>Hello, my name is </p></span>

<span> <input id="txt" value="12345" class="form"  type="text"size='5' >
</span>
<button id="change"> change </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific event that fires when a value is set, you can set the value through javascript instead of server side language on document load `$(document).ready(function(){});` and fix the length accordingly.

Or, if this is going to happen on change also, you can set a change listener and trigger it whenever you set the value:

```
var myValue = 'Any value';

// trigger change whenever you set a value
$('#myInputId').val(myValue).trigger('change');

$('#myInputId').change(function(){ // fix the length });
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#txt").change(function() {            
            $(this).attr('style', "width: " + (($(this).val().length + 1) * 8) + "px");
        });
        $("#txt").trigger("change");
    })
</script>
<span><p>Hello, my name is </p></span>

<span> <input id="txt" value="I am coming from db" readonly="readonly" class="form" type="text" >
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your requirement correctly 
You can add a script tag after the element will work fine anyway as below

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span><p>Hello, my name is </p></span>

<span> <input id="txt" value="I am coming from db" readonly="readonly" class="form"  type="text" >
</span>
<script>
var elelement = document.getElementById("txt");
elelement.style.width = ((elelement.value.length + 1) * 8) + 'px'
</script>
```

You can also do it in document ready method

Select element and adjust it width.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var element = document.getElementById("txt");
    element.style.width = ((element.value.length + 1) * 8) + 'px'
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#txt').on('change', function() {
  $(this).width(($(this).val().length + 1) * 8);
});

setTimeout(function() {
   $('#txt').val('sdsds sdsdsdsd sddsdsdsdsds sddsdsds');
  $('#txt').trigger('change');
}, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span><p>Hello, my name is </p></span>

<span> <input id="txt" value="I am coming from db" readonly="readonly" class="form" type="text" >
</span>
```